# Why don't Internet browsers allow me to fetch a JSON file from raw.githubusercontent.com, but they allow me to fetch .psm files from there?

Tags: xss, javascript

When I was making my [PicoBlaze Simulator in JavaScript](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze), I added 6 examples of how to use it. Those examples are on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS), they are the `.psm` (PicoBlaze Assembly) files. I decided not to hard-code the links to those `.psm` files in my JavaScript, but to write a [JSON file containing the links to them](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/blob/master/examples.json). However, I remember that browsers would not allow me to `fetch` that `examples.json` file from `raw.githubusercontent.com`, that I had to copy `examples.json` from my GitHub profile to my website in order to be able to `fetch` it. Nevertheless, browsers do allow me to `fetch` the `.psm` files from my GitHub profile. Why is it so?

What is the threat model because of which browsers do not allow one to `fetch` `.json` files from `raw.githubusercontent.com`? I understand that it is not a good idea to take JavaScript `.js` files directly from somebody's GitHub profile: files on somebody's GitHub profile are not supposed to be well-tested (That's why you are not supposed to download the source code of some program from GitHub to build it, as many websites warn you, "*There can quite possibly be bugs, in fact, the code might not even compile.*"). Furthermore, one who owns that file (and browsers cannot know it is me) could easily do a cross-site scripting attack on every website that uses that JavaScript if that were allowed. But `.json` files are not executable JavaScript, they cannot contain cross-site scripting attacks. So, why aren't browsers allowing us to `fetch` `.json` files from `raw.githubusercontent.com`?

In [my Bachelor Thesis](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.rtf), I speculate that that decision dates back to the time when JSON was parsed using `eval` (rather than `JSON.parse`), so that somebody could indeed make a cross-site scripting attack by modifying the `.json` file to contain invalid JSON (which `JSON.parse` would reject, but `eval` would accept). Is that correct?

Comment: *"browsers would not allow me to fetch that examples.json file from raw.githubusercontent.com"* - is this your interpretation or do you have a clear error message which states this? In the first case: how do you come to this interpretation? In the latter case: what exactly was the error message?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/something.json')').then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => console.log(json));` is fetching the JSON from GitHub and printing it to the console. Could you have an own _Content Security Policy_ in place preventing the fetch?

Comment: What browser plugins are you using? Did you change the default browser settings?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It was three years ago. If I remember correctly, the browser complained that `raw.githubusercontent.com` set the response type to be `text/plain`, rather than `application/json`.

Comment: @FlatAssembler: The content-type used by the server is irrelevant unless you specifically expected one in your fetch request, which can not be seen from the information provided. I propose to close this question unless you can provide something to reproduce  the problem *now*, instead of asking about something which happens 3 years ago and which you vaguely remember.  As you can see in the comments - others cannot reproduce your problem based on the few information you've provided.

Comment: The error can be reproduced in Chromium 73 with Opaque Responses (I haven't tested other browsers): `fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/master/examples.json", {mode: "no-cors"});` This results in the error message: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/master/examples.json with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you describe is either [Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/) or [Opaque Response Blocking (ORB)](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4933785622675456). It blocks specific media types like `application/json`, `text/plain` and `text/html`, while other types are accepted. You can reproduce the error in older browsers (I've tested Chromium 73, not sure about Firefox). The code is as follows:

```
<script>
    jsonUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/master/examples.json"; 
    fetch(jsonUrl, {mode: "no-cors"});
</script>
```

This will produce the following error message:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/master/examples.json
with MIME type text/plain. 
See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

A possible explanation for why you might have ended up with `no-cors` mode is that `raw.githubusercontent.com` didn't always allow CORS. In that case, the browser will recommend using `no-cors`, which in turns leads to the above error.

Currently, `raw.githubusercontent.com` does allow CORS, so it should be possible to `fetch` any resource in `cors` mode, regardless of the type. In `no-cors` mode, modern browsers no longer seem to display the above CORB error. However, the error *is* still displayed when you try to load the JSON file with a `script` element.

As to the idea behind this feature: CORB has nothing to do with preventing cross-site scripting. Instead, it is supposed to prevent cross-origin access to sensitive data through side-channel attacks like Spectre and Meltdown. The attack scenario is that a file which may contain sensitive user data (like HTML, XML or JSON) is loaded from a malicious website through an `img` or `script` element or `fetch` in `no-cors` mode. This is possible despite the same-origin policy and without CORS headers. Scripts from the malicious site cannot directly access the response, but the file content will be loaded into browser memory in order to render, execute or cache it. Through Spectre or Meltdown, it may then be possible to access the content in memory through Spectre/Meltdown exploits written in JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I remember I was using Firefox.

Comment: Firefox has Opaque Response Blocking (ORB) with a similar purpose.

Comment: @Ja1024: from my understanding the question is specifically about [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and not about including content using img or script.

Comment: CORB also applies to `fetch` in `no-cors` mode.